# Separate Execution context for Visualforce Page?

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, governorlimits

So i have a Visualforce Page which have 5 VF components(See Example below).

```
<apex:page controller="InsightController" sidebar="false">
    <c:component1 />
    <c:component2 />
    <c:component3 />
    <c:component4 />
    <c:component5 />
</apex:page>
```

Does this VF page have 6 different Execution Context?
I tried to check the debug logs and i get seperate debug Logs for each Component and their limit usage, which is understandable because each component have their own controller.

I also understand that Limit usage applies per execution context.
How can i get consolidated limit usage for my VF page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe these do exist in different contexts because there is a design pattern that uses a base class for both the page and component controllers and facilitates communications between them. This pattern could be used to enable communication between the component controller instances also, so maybe you could track limits by having them share data via static class members or even a singleton?